# What hooks are called when "wp_update_post" and "wp_insert_post" are used?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-hook

Are there any hooks that are called when someone calls either: `wp_update_post` or `wp_insert_post`?

I can't seem to tell, but from [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) it seems that the `save_post` hook is not called. Is there another hook I can listen to?

Comment: `save_post` is fired by both of those functions. `wp_update_post` internally calls `wp_insert_post` and sets a `$update` parameter if the information already has a post ID, and within the `wp_insert_post` the `save_post` action is fired.

Comment: Here is the code for `wp_insert_post`: https://3v4l.org/kpg0a look at line 494, you can see the action being fired there.

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to modify or hook into? Do you want to modify the post itself or some other related data to the post?